# Rails Notification Without Page Refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery

I created a simple private messaging app through rails, but I am trying to get it to simply show that new message has arrived without the person having to refresh the page.

I am looking at State Machine because I am thinking that it might be a part of building something like this. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do that using javascript is to periodically send requests to the server using `setTimeout` + `$.get()`.

Another a little bit more complicated way is to use gems like [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) . There is nice [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at any of the messaging protocols like:

[Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/)

[Socket.IO](http://socket.io/)

or hosted sollutions like
[PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) or [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)